# How do I correctly use IndexRoute in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am using React for a small web-app. It has a basic 5 page website layout. (Home|About|Contact|Press|Shows) so I wanted to use an app template that just displays a menu, the header and the footer, and the `{props.children}` would be the React Router's route component. To achieve this, I used the following code. Assume all the imports are there...

Here is my router code:

```
export default (props) => {
    return (
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path="/" component={ Template }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home }></IndexRoute>
                <Route path="about"   component={ About }></Route>
                <Route path="music"   component={ Music }></Route>
                <Route path="store"   component={ Store }></Route>
                <Route path="shows"   component={ Shows }></Route>
                <Route path="contact" component={ Contact }></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Now here is my template:

```
export default ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Menu />
            { props.children }
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I know something is wrong, b/c without CSS magic, a:active is always HOME and any other active pages. I.E. if I click About, then both Home and About are active. How can I correctly use an index route, or should I even use an index route in this simple of an app? If not, then how else can I use a template like the one I have and pass in a page as a component in a different way?

Update: Here is my Menu.js file...

```
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <nav>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="about">About</Link>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="music">Music</Link>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="shows">Shows</Link>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="store">Store</Link>
            <Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="contact">Contact</Link>
          </nav>
          <hr className="line" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: since every url starts with `/` a:active will always show Home as active. I would suggest to put something like `path='home'` and use indexRedirect.

Comment: or if you want some links to be active if only Home component is rendered, then use `<IndexLink />` from react-router.

Comment: @Vikramaditya, this doesn't solve my issue of using a DRY template? Could you provide a more concise answer?

Comment: how are you styling the active route?

Comment: @QoP, forget about styles, it's irrelevant to my question...

Comment: I was asking about the code you are using to mark the route as active, not about the styles.

Comment: are you using <Link/> component?

Comment: @Utro, I added my menu code for you...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for index route you should use [IndexLink](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexlink) comp , otherwise 'Home' will be active allways

```
import {Link,IndexLink} from 'react-router';

<IndexLink activeClassName="nav-active" to="/">Home</IndexLink>
<Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="about">About</Link>
<Link activeClassName="nav-active" to="music">Music</Link>
 ...
```